# Nodejs hide all calls to node_modules/ in error stack trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Whenever in Nodejs something goes wrong, from syntax error to not found error. Everything gets printed, usually that results in 30 lines of node_modules all being vomited out to command line. Which only hides your files in haystack.

Is there a way to highlight with color only your files in stack trace of all errors produced by nodejs OR just hide all files that were inside node_modules.

Usually like this

```
...

    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\Projects\tictac\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:773:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:734:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:711:5)
...
```